# How can gravitational energy cancel out the rest energy of mass in the universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, energy-conservation, universe

I've heard that some physicists think that the net energy of the universe is zero. For this to happen, I would assume that the negative gravitational energy of a body ought to cancel out its rest energy. A back-of-the envelope calculation for the Earth gives me a rest energy around $10^9$ greater than its gravitational energy. I would assume that for other ordinary matter we get a disparity on the same order of magnitude. This means that the rest-energy of ordinary matter far outweighs its gravitational energy. Even if ordinary matter only contributes 4% of the gravitational energy in the universe, a claim I've heard, the rest energy of ordinary matter still far outweighs the total gravitational energy in the universe. So how is it still a plausible hypothesis that the net energy of the universe is zero? Where does the rest of the negative energy come from?

Comment: Arguments about the total energy of the universe are almost, but not entirely, complete rowlocks because they depend on lots of assumptions. Physicists can't even agree [whether the total energy of the universe is conserved or not](http://blog.vixra.org/2010/08/17/energy-is-conserved-in-cosmology/).

Answer (score 2):

*I've heard that some physicists think that the net energy of the universe is zero.*

Me too. They talk about gravitational energy being negative. But see Einstein talking about gravitataionl field energy [here](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/197?highlightText=gravitatively). It's positive.

*For this to happen, I would assume that the negative gravitational energy of a body ought to cancel out its rest energy.*

That's what they say, but IMHO like John Rennie said, it's wrong. When two bodies falls together, some of their rest-mass energy is converted into kinetic energy. They collide, and the kinetic energy is converted into heat and eventually gets radiated away. Then you'[re left with a [mass deficit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation). But it's a mass deficit, not an energy deficit. Conservation of energy applies. You don't end up with less energy than what you started with.

*A back-of-the envelope calculation for the Earth gives me a rest energy around $10^9$   greater than its gravitational energy...*

Yes, gravitational field energy isn't much. Nor is the mass deficit.

*So how is it still a plausible hypothesis that the net energy of the universe is zero?*

IMHO it isn't. IMHO the people who say this sort of thing tend to be popscience cosmologists with a book to plug.

Comment: +1 for the statement *the people who say this sort of thing tend to be popscience cosmologists with a book to plug* :-)

Comment: @John Rennie : thanks John. I have to say I have watched  cosmology programs on the Discovery Channel, and have wanted to throw cushions at the TV. Naming no names of course. ;)